# Javascript Array to Object

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like so:

```
files = [
  'Dashboard/Logs/Errors',
  'Dashboard/Logs/Other',
  'Accounts/Main',
]
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
navigation = [
  {
    "title": "Dashboard",
    "dropdown": [
      {
        "title": "Logs",
        "dropdown": [
          {
            "title": "Errors",
          },
          {
            "title": "Other",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Accounts",
    "dropdown": [
      {
        "title": "Main",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have the following so far:

```
var navigation = [];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  var parts = files[i].split('/');
  navigation.push({title: parts[0]});
  for (var j = 1; j < parts.length; j++) {

  }
}
```

I am having difficulties figuring out a decent way to do this. What I have so far already doesn't work because it creates two objects under navigation each with `title: "Dashboard"`. Any ideas for a clever approach? Thanks :)

Comment: Whats navigation? `navigation = [];` ?

Comment: @Alec  Is the depth of the object hierarchy fixed ? or is there a maximum depth atleast ?

Comment: @kulkarniankita `navigation` is defined right there. The end result should be `navigation`.

Comment: @MikeC right although navigation is something he wants as a end result so he needs to declare it in order to push elements

Comment: @kulkarniankita No they don't. They're showing an example output. This does not pertain to the problem.

Comment: @stark, unfortunately the depth is variable throughout :( Maximum depth of 10 is safe (that is a lot of dropdowns ;) )

Comment: This would make a great interview question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should produce the desired output:

```
var files = [
  'Dashboard/Logs/Errors',
  'Dashboard/Logs/Other',
  'Accounts/Main',
];

var navigation = [];
// Iterates through a navigation array and returns the object with matching title, if one exists.
var getNavigationObject = function(nav, title) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nav.length; i++) {
    if (nav[i].title == title) {
      return nav[i];
    }
  }
};
// Adds a file to the nav.
// The input is an array of file components (i.e. file.split('/'))
// This works by recursively adding each component of a file.
var addToNav = function (nav, components) {
  var n = getNavigationObject(nav, components[0]);
  if (!n) {
    n = {
      title: components[0]
    };
    nav.push(n);
  }
  if (components.length > 1) {
    n.dropdown = n.dropdown || [];
    addToNav(n.dropdown, components.slice(1));
  }
};

// Actually call `addToNav` on each file.
files.forEach(function(e) {
  addToNav(navigation, e.split('/'));
});

// Produces the result in string form.
JSON.stringify(navigation, null, 2)
```

This works by recursively checking if a given element already matches the component of the file.  If it does, it recurs into that component's "dropdown".  Otherwise, it creates it.

Comment: Clarified.  Wrote it in a hurry--certainly not production level code. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach with a temporary object and some array methods with no search overhead.

```js
var files = ['Dashboard/Logs/Errors', 'Dashboard/Logs/Other', 'Accounts/Main'],
    navigation = function (data) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var s = r;
            a.split('/').reduce(function (p, b) {
                if (p.children) {
                    p.value.dropdown = p.value.dropdown || [];
                    s = p.value.dropdown;
                    p = p.children;
                }
                if (!(b in p)) {
                    p[b] = { value: { title: b }, children: {} };
                    s.push(p[b].value);
                }
                return p[b];
            }, o);
        });
        return r;
    }(files);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(navigation, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```